# Is there a way that I can implement as many methods as I want in an inherited class in an automated way?

Tags: c++, inheritance, state-machine

I couldn't think of a good title to say what I meant. I have a class that would be a good way to create a state machine (execute certain parts of code based on a value) without having a bunch of switch statements.

This is what I have:

```
#pragma once

class StateMachine
{
public:
    StateMachine();
    void Run();
protected:
    void State1();
    void State2();
    void State3();
    void State4();
    void Change();
    int State;
    bool Cont;
};

#include "StateMachine.h"

StateMachine::StateMachine() {
    State = 0;
}
void StateMachine::Run() {
    Cont = true;
    while (Cont) {
        Cont = false;
        switch (State) {
        case 0:
            State1();
            break;
        case 1:
            State2();
            break;
        case 2:
            State3();
            break;
        case 3:
            State4();
            break;
        }
    }
}
void StateMachine::State1() {

}
void StateMachine::State2() {

}
void StateMachine::State3() {

}
void StateMachine::State4() {

}

void StateMachine::Change() {
    State++;
    Cont = true;
}
```

This would be good as a base class. It could work if it has enough methods that I could implement, but if it has too many then it is just like I am wasting things.

Is there a way that I could explicitly change the amount to the amount that I need? Could there be something like an array of function pointers, even if I would just have to create a lot, like 200 or so? And what is there that I can put in a private section?

Comment: Of course there's a way. It's called "scripting". Write a script, in your favorite scripting language that robo-generates C++ code, that gets `#include`d in the right place. There's nothing like that in C++ itself, instead an external script gets integrated into the build system.

Comment: Code generation.  You can use a scripting language - write code in some other language and (hopefully) effort to write the script is less than the effort to write the code it generates.   Before doing that, however, look carefully at your requirement - a lot perceived needs for repetitive code (e.g. wanting to generate 200 functions named `State1` to `State200`) are due to copy/paste approaches and can be simplified by *redesign* rather than code generation.

Comment: If you can fix the inputs and outputs of the state machine, you can take a page from the book of Hardware Engineers and implement "microprogramming". Basically you make one big table where each row is uniquely indexed by the permutation of the inputs. Each row contains the outputs for that state. You determine the next state by simply enabling the row that your inputs are indexing.